# type of industry based on stock ticker symbol

Tags: stocks, stock-analysis

Is there a way to know given a stock symbol which sector it is related to?

ie; bioscience or mining or construction or manufacturing?

For example:- if APPL is the stock how can I related that to manufacturing or finance or construction?

Comment: I forgot to mention that the screener at FINVIZ provides the sector and industry of the 7,600 stocks that is lists (just added that to my answer and noting it here in case you miss that edit).

Comment: Keep in mind that many large companies cannot really be defined within one single industry. Shipping companies may be involved with oil and gas too; and for example apple will have significant exposure towards retail trade and real estate too - essentially making it more complex than saying they are categorized as “Electronics” or similar.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The SEC uses [Standard Industrial Classification](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Standard_Industrial_Classification) to classify each regulated company.

When you make search on [EDGAR](https://www.sec.gov/cgi-bin/browse-edgar?CIK=320193&owner=exclude), it shows that AAPL has "SIC: 3571 - ELECTRONIC COMPUTERS".

A list of commonly used SIC is on the [SEC website](https://www.sec.gov/info/edgar/siccodes.htm).

The SEC also provides an [API service](https://www.sec.gov/edgar/searchedgar/accessing-edgar-data.htm) but I can't be sure that the SIC of the company is there.

Answer (score 1):

Stock symbols do not reflect the sector that a company is in.

They may reflect the type of security (based on the suffix) such as the exchange it trades on, a preferred stock, a warrant or right, ADR, units, etc.

However, the screener at FINVIZ provides the sector and industry of the 7,600 stocks that is lists.

Answer (score 0):

No, in the US, at least, because ticker symbols are **only** based on the name of the company.

(Besides, big companies can be in multiple sectors; this was quite common in the "conglomeration craze" of the 1960s.)

Comment: Not by a fixed scheme, but perhaps by lookup with an API to a data provider?

Comment: @nanoman that's a completely different question, probably off-topic (either due to being a software recommendation or a programming exercise).